# Preloading records using Store.pushPayload doesn't preserver hasMany relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using DS.Store's "pushPayload" method to preload some records when my application starts.

The payload is in the proper "normalized" form:

Example:

```
{"provinces":[
    {"id":1,"name":"Ontario","city_ids":[1,2,3]}
], 
"cities":[
    {"id":1,"name":"Toronto","slug":"toronto"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Hamilton","slug":"hamilton"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Waterloo","slug":"waterloo"}
]}
```

Chrome's Ember Inspector tells me that both my Provinces and Cities have been loaded, as they show up the Data tab.

However, doing something like province.get('cities') on one of my provinces objects returns an empty DS.ManyArray.

This leads me to believe that while the Cities were loaded, their references weren't hooked up properly, or need refreshing. How can I make sure this happens and Provinces have references to their respective Cities (and vice-versa)? Of course, I have the proper DS.hasMany and DS.belongsTo relationships set up in the model files.

EDIT: So while I can access the relationship on the "hasMany" side, the "belongsTo" side doesn't get populated, and is null. Hmmm...

Comment: are you using the active model adapter/serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh! It turns out I couldn't iterate the relationship using a CoffeeScript "for/in" loop, because it's not a plain array.

Iterating using the "forEach" method worked; the data was there all along, I just didn't know how to get to it...

Comment: Like I mentioned in my edit, this doesn't actually fix my problem, as I still get a null value on the "belongsTo" side of the relationship!

Comment: Have you tried using cities instead of city_ids as key in provinces?